# Modulo function from python to julia efficiency

Tags: julia

In python I can use this to get an array with no value for the modulo for z if I set x and y:

```
import numpy as np

y= np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
x=2
z=y[:len(y) % x*-1]


print(z)
```

Output:

```
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
```

Is there a more efficient way to write the variable `z` in julia rather than doing this:

```
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
x = 2
z= y[1:(length(y) - (length(y)%x))]

println(z)
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `end`, e.g.

```
z=y[1:end-end%x]
```